# how to save my image while changing the orientation of my phone in androidStudio using Kotlin

Tags: android, image, kotlin, orientation

how to save the image while changing the orientation of my android app And this is basically a simple roll dice app i.e. base on the random number  and on the basis of this we can easily choose image using when() in kotlin
package com.example.rollingdice

```
    import android.location.Address
    import android.media.Image
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.PersistableBundle
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.TextView
    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator
    import kotlin.properties.Delegates
    import kotlin.random.Random
    
    abstract class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        lateinit var showingResult:ImageView
        lateinit var diceButton:Button
        lateinit var result
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            diceButton=findViewById(R.id.rollDice)
            showingResult=findViewById(R.id.iv)
            diceButton.setOnClickListener {
                rollingDice()
            }
        }
 // accordin to me this function is use to save the data or image while changing the 
    orientation
        override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle, outPersistentState: PersistableBundle) {

            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState)
            outState.putInt("img",result)
        }
      //private function named as rollingDice()
    
        private fun rollingDice() {
           var number : Int= Random.nextInt(6)+1
       // taking random number input in when()
            when (number){
              // taking number in when() statement to choose the image
               1 -> R.drawable.dice_1
               2 -> R.drawable.dice_2
               3 -> R.drawable.dice_3
               4 -> R.drawable.dice_4
               5 -> R.drawable.dice_5
               else -> R.drawable.dice_6
             // else condition give the dice_6 name image as a result
           }
            showingResult.setImageResource(result)
        //i'm taking the result as  aimage in the image view
        }
    
    
    }
```

Comment: Using instance state for maintaining data through configuration changes is obsolete. A ViewModel can be used instead, and is much cleaner. But if you were using it, the object you store has to be a primitive, primitive array, Parcelable, or Serializable. And you would restore it in `onCreate` using the passed Bundle.

Comment: `result` should not be `lateinit` if you aren't setting it immediately in `onCreate()`.

Comment: can you pls tell me any youtube video for view model please sir

Comment: and after putting result in onCreate() methos i cannot used it in other methods

Comment: I learned ViewModel exclusively from the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel). `result` should be defined before `onCreate`, but its initial value must be set in `onCreate()` if it is `lateinit`. If it doesn't have an initial value, make it nullable instead of `lateinit`.

Comment: If `result` is a Int (I don't know what type you have), it should be declared as `val result: Int? = null`, for example. You only should use `lateinit` when you know you will set the initial value in `onCreate` so it will never be null.

Comment: you are great sir

Comment: please help sir my account of stackover flow is block